# How to combine XML attributes?

Tags: android, xml

In an Android XML file, if I want to combine attributes, say, for inputType as listed in 
[android:inputType list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)
is it possible to get the effect of 'capitalize all characters' AND 'turn off suggestions'?
What I want is both "textCapCharacters" and "textNoSuggestions"
The doc doesn't say I can combine them, but it seems like it should be possible to do so.
Is it possible to specify both somehow?

In addition, I just tried only "textNoSuggestions" with the emulator, and when I start typing something in, I still get suggestions. Is this a bug in the emulator?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have not tried it myself but have you read:

> Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant
>   values.

Written before the table in the link you provided...
The details there suggest they can be combined with all other variations of text.

Comment: I missed that, thanks! using "textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters" looks like it's good syntax. However, setting the 'textNoSuggestions' tag still results in suggestions for the EditText widget, looks like that part is broken. In fact, setting *only* that bit still results in suggestions. Is there someplace that would like to know about bugs like this?